# Compare two almost equal strings from Html page

Tags: bash

I have a html page, which contains two strings. And I have to compare them. 
My plan is:

```
string =(curl <path>)
echo "$string"
```

Then I get from *echo*:

```
Base Regresses: latency = 0 latency_max = 1 latency_min = 1 bandwidth = 0 
Opp Regresses: latency = 4 latency_max = 4 latency_min = 3 bandwidth = 3
```

Now I have to find `latency_max` and `bandwidth` in `Base` mode and in `Opp` mode.

And compare their numbers, like:

```
Compare: (Base) 1 and (Opp)4
Compare: (Base) 0 and (Opp)3
```

Can you suggest, how I should find these numbers?

Comment: please include HTML tags in your example

Comment: @oguzismail Sorry, I have researched and found out some new things about. And I have edited the question.

Comment: why not just grep and extract the numbers from the string ???

Comment: @Inder please, show if you can. Because I couldn't connect `$string` with `grep`

Comment: `echo "$string"| grep -oP '(?<=latency_max\s=\s)([0-9]*)'` something like this